# cordova-sqlite-storage plugin conflicting native iOS framework's sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I have a native iOS chat frameworks which uses sqlite for storage. Now I have to integrate this native iOS chat framework in Cordova/ionic app.

However, after adding native iOS chat framework in Cordova/ionic app I'm able to use the native iOS chat framework properly and I'm able to send and receive the messages.

Now, if I add 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin which I have to use for data storage of Cordova/ionic app the native iOS chat framework stops working and I'm not able to send and receive the messages.

How can I resolve this dependency conflict after using 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin.

The workaround I have done is, I tried to run my squlite queries/operations which are present in the native iOS chat framework on a separate thread.

Earlier I was running my sqlite operations using below dispatch_queue:

```
NSObject <OS_dispatch_queue> *queue_database_operations;
```

Now, I have created different dispach_async_t queue as below:

```
dispatch_queue_t globalConcurrentQ;
```

And running my native iOS chat frameworks queries on the new thread which I have created above.

After doing this, I'm able to use my native iOS chat SDK along with 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin in my Cordova/Ionic app and messaging works properly.

Now, when I remove the plugin and add it again then the messaging stops working.

I'm only able to use the native iOS chat framework and 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin in my Cordova/Ionic app only for the first time.

Second time when I remove the 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin and add it again then messaging stops.

The issue I'm facing is I'm only able to run  native iOS chat framework and 'cordova-sqlite-storage' plugin only for the first time once I remove it and add it again then the messaging stops.

Also, I tried this stupid thing, I tried to run native iOS chat framework's sqlite operations on the Main thread, everything works fine but this is not a feasible solution as you're only suppose to perform only UI related operations on Main thread. Doing this I'm able to achieve my goal but this is not proper solution as it makes the UI laggy/slow.